# create collectionView when tapped on a button

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hi , how can I make this using a collection view ?
or when I tap on a button , It'll create a collectionView in my view controller .
Actually I want to add a collection view but I want the number of it to be dynamically cause I'm getting it's count from a server . 
Please help me .

[image]

Comment: What about showing us some code, so that we can know what you have tried so far?

Comment: This question is way to broad. I suggest you look into the UICollectionView documentation and update the question with some code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Comment: @CodeHut I've created a view controller with 2 collectionViews inside . but when I get 3 parts that I should place them in the third collectionView I don't have it.I want get the count of my collectionViews from the server , so when it is 3 or 4 , my current and main collectionView  will recreate for 3 times in the continues of that . actually have colletcionViews dynamically . I don't have any code cause I don't know how to create it .

Comment: @zasgh, this is actually a screen with embedded UITableView, and it's cell contains UICollectionView inside.

Comment: Here is a picture for better explanation: https://imgur.com/a/9UvuL1O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,I hope this will help you,

//viewcontroller.swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

//Tableviewcell.swift

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet var collectionview2: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var collectionview1: UICollectionView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collectionview1.dataSource = self
         collectionview1.delegate = self
         collectionview2.dataSource = self
         collectionview2.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(collectionView == collectionview1){
            return 5
        }else{
            return 10
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if(collectionView == collectionview1){
            let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }else {
            let  cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
            return cell1
        }

    }


}
```

Finally set "collectionview1" scroll direction has Horizontal and set "collectionview2" scroll direction has Vertical.

Comment: I did it but it gives me this error : 
outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content

Comment: when u getting this error , while trying to give outlet for collectionview or someother else..

Comment: I think you are trying to connect your collectionviewcell labels and buttons in UItableviewcell subclass that is wrong,you of to create a subclass for UIcollectionviewcell and connect outlet in that subclass.